# Why str[:len(str) / 2] but not str[:len(str) * 0.5]?

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, division, multiplication

I'm playing on coding bat and

```
return str[:len(str) / 2]
```

works fine but

```
return str[:len(str) * 0.5]
```

returns

```
Error:slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

and although I can kind of speculate as to why this is I am very interested in hearing a better informed explanation. Thank you!

Bonus Points: Offer a tag I can place on this post so that we can categorize it well!

Comment: Multiplying by 0.5 returns a float, and you must use integers in slices. Whereas dividing by 2 (assuming Python 2.x) always returns an integer.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2:

Dividing two integers results in an integer.

Multiplying an integer and a float results in a float.

Slices must be integer.

Comment: *Only in Python 2

Comment: To expand on @juanpa.arrivillaga, in Python 3 you need to use `//` to get integer division, even if both operands are integers.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga added clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In python, slices *must* be integers (`5.0` is wrong, `5` is good).

## In python 2

```
len(str) / 5 # => integer
len(str) * 0.5 # => float
```

## In python 3

```
len(str) / 5 # => float
len(str) // 5 # => integer (equivalent of math.floor(len(str) / 5))
```